# Why I need to click to make my angular app render?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-calendar

My app is at [here](https://timegarden.io). When I have a fast connection, it doesn't have problem. But when I simulate a slow connection, I have to touch/click the screen in order for my app to render. I think it's specific to my usage of [angular-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar). Anyone has any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Hi! It is perfectly loading at my screen. Can you explain a little about your problem, and exactly in which place you encounter any difficulty in getting rendered?

Comment: @DulanjayaTennekoon the typeform is ok, it's the calendar widget that has problem. To see the problem register an account by entering "roy" as invitation code, then you should see the calendar widget on the home screen. To see the problem, throttle in chome to be fast 3G speed, then refresh home screen.